# How to use partials in Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I want to make a navigation menu with the titles of published pages. In the [user manual](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Tags#partial) I can see the format which I should use in the layout:

```
{{ cms:partial:path/to/partial }}
```

So I create a partial with a name `_navmenu.html.haml` and place it in `app/views/` directory. I think I should refer to this partial like this :

```
 {{ cms:partial:app/views/navmenu}}
```

but I only see the error message of the ActionController:

```
Missing partial app/views/navbar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/qumara/mexicansofa/app/views"
```

It seems it searches in `app/views` directory. I suppose partial in Comfy is referred by Rails conventions (with underscore prefix).

The stack: Ruby on Rails 3.2.14, comfortable-mexican-sofa 1.8.4 .

How should I refer (from the layout) to a partial in Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It knows its already in `app/views` so simply `{{ cms:partial:navmenu }}` should work

If you have it in a folder within `app/views`, `app/views/admin/navmenu` for example it would be `{{ cms:partial:admin/navmenu }}`

Edit: For people that haven't read the comments, the answer is to put the file you are trying to render inside a folder within `views` then it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the naming convention the same as in Rails : `_navmenu.html.haml` (with underscore)?

Comment: yes, exactly the same, comfy literally calls <% render :partial => :foo %>

Comment: It is really strange: I did the things that we discuss and the error message changed : `Missing partial cms_content/navbar, application/navbar with ....` . Now the search is in `cms_content` and `application` ? In case that I am not aware of directory with a name `application`...

Comment: Hehe `navbar` vs `navmenu` ?

Comment: Actually I use `_navbar` , it is not a typo unfortunately. `navmenu` was only example. Got an eye, I admit it...

Comment: Ok, thought it might have been... Looking at my app i don't have any views that are just in the views directory, they are all in sub folders. 

Apart from the subfolder thing, im doing exactly the same: `{{ cms:partial:components/page_list }}` and thats stored in `app/views/components/_page_list.html.haml`

Comment: I'll try to move it on a subfolder, nice idea indeed.

Comment: Where is located your `components` dir? And what is your comfy version?

Comment: Yeeeyyyy! That was it: when I created a separated dir `components` (I should pay royalties to you), it all happened!!! Thank you for your patience and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Im actually using a fork of comfy, with some(quite nice) added features, check it out: https://github.com/homeserve-alliance/comfortable-mexican-sofa

Comment: Your efforts are remarkable. Really useful features are added.